# Mysql multiple columns index

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE album SET x=1 WHERE store_id=:store_id && type=:type && time<:time
```

I have a Mysql update query, My question is how can I set up the index for this query

I create index in phpMyadmin, should I select store_id, type, time together and create one index?

Comment: Do you know what index is used for at all?

Comment: Try not to use `&&` in SQL. The operator is `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are searching by store_id and type and time together then yes you can create INDEX for those three.

BUT,

if sometimes you are searching only by store_id  then here you should use index only in store_id

if you search by store_id and type then index will be on those two columns.

so it depeneds what are columns you using to search.

here how to use to create what index you want.

```
  ALTER TABLE `album` ADD INDEX `myindex` (`store_id`) --for store_id
  ALTER TABLE `album` ADD INDEX `myindex` (`store_id` ,`type`,`time`) --for store_id and type and time
  and so on ....
```

choose which one you want.

Comment: what if i have another query search store_id only, do I need to create 2 index, 1-store_id only 2.three columns together?

Comment: only store_id you need , for better performanse use only index on store_id.

Comment: you dont have to make index on time.

Comment: @BenWong Yes! If sometimes you query for store_id only and sometimes for store_id and other columns then you have to create a separate index for each case. In your case you could also have several separate indices: (store_id), (store_id, type), (store_id, time), (store_id, type, time), ...  But adding indices makes insert/update/delete statements much slower, so dont add them if it is not necessary.

Comment: in this case do I need put time into index too? Gordon Linoff's answer put time into it

Comment: if your seach for time yes put it for quick result. if you dont use time then better not use it for quick result also and better performance.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up an index, the place to start is the `where` clause:

```
WHERE store_id=:store_id && type=:type && time<:time
```

Start with the equality comparisons.  Then you can choose one column for inequality.  For this query, the best index would have all three columns:

```
create index album_storeid_type_time on album(store_id, type, time);
```